# crystal report for work operations

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have a problem during creating a crystal report which will show a part of one manufacturing process.
So, I need your help....

I have a four different components that forms a one bigger component (or product). Every of this small components pass through different production operations, but the same component don't pass through all production production  operations.

And, I need a crystal report which shows every article (component) with a number of finished component in each operation.

Here is the example of SQL result (ordery by operations):

[image: sql result]

so, you can see that article with articleID = '29183' is going through first and last operation... also, articleID = '17275' is going through the second and last operation... I think that is all clear from the picture...

And, all I need is report that this will show in the columns like this:

[image: "report result" THIS I NEED]

In the report, I made a group by ArticleID, so the article (component) appears only in one row... And after that, I need a values in columns (columns for operations) which correspond to every article...

Very thanks... I try this solve for a few days, but I don't know how to solve this... I tried crosstabs, dictionaries, lists but nothing helps me

Comment: also, you can post a link of any tutorial for this if something like this already is solved...

Comment: My consulting rate is $125/hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already grouped by Article ID so that each article has its own single line, so that's a good start. Now, you just need to separate the 3 operations with 3 formulas and aggregate them to the group level.

For example, the formula for the first operation would look like:

```
//If row is a "first operation" then display the finished data element
if {table.Operation}="first operation" then {table.Finished}
```

Then to display in the Group Footer you could just use a `max()` summary function on the formula you just created.

Comment: I tried this and this isn't good... bacause, when the report grouped by articleID then only one operation (first operation of article) is showed for each article.... and value for the second or last article isn't showed....

Comment: That's because you need three summaries for your three formulas that you have to create (one for each operation).